# Spring boot constructor parameter which is greater then 7 authorized

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have an implementation of my service class with a constructor having more than 7 parameters (11 parameters)

```
@Service
public class CourseService extends CourseBase {

  private MathRepository mathRepository;
  private BiologyRepository biologyRepository;
  private PhysicalRepository physicalRepository;
  private EnglishRepository englishRepository;
  private AlgebraRepository algebraRepository;
  private TrigonometryRepository trigonometryRepository;
  private ChemistryRepository chemistryRepository;
  private AnatomyRepository anatomyRepository;
  private HistoryRepository historyRepository;
  private CourseBaseOneRepository courseBaseOneRepository;
  private CourseBaseTwoRepository courseBaseTwoRepository;
  
  public CourseService(
    MathRepository mathRepository,
    BiologyRepository biologyRepository,
    PhysicalRepository physicalRepository,
    EnglishRepository englishRepository,
    AlgebraRepository algebraRepository,
    TrigonometryRepository trigonometryRepository,
    ChemistryRepository chemistryRepository,
    AnatomyRepository anatomyRepository,
    HistoryRepository historyRepository,
    CourseBaseOneRepository courseBaseOneRepository,
    CourseBaseTwoRepository courseBaseTwoRepository
  ) {
  super(courseBaseOneRepository, courseBaseTwoRepository);
    this.mathRepository = mathRepository;
    this.biologyRepository = biologyRepository;
    this.physicalRepository = physicalRepository;
    this.englishRepository = englishRepository;
    this.algebraRepository = algebraRepository;
    this.trigonometryRepository = trigonometryRepository;
    this.chemistryRepository = chemistryRepository;
    this.anatomyRepository = anatomyRepository;
    this.historyRepository = historyRepository;
  }
  ...

}
```

I get a  sonar Qube error: constructor has 11 parameters , which is greater then 7 authorized
To solve this error, I thought of creating another class that has 9 parameters and I want to inject this class into my service class.

```
public class CourseGroupService {

  private MathRepository mathRepository;
  private BiologyRepository biologyRepository;
  private PhysicalRepository physicalRepository;
  private EnglishRepository englishRepository;
  private AlgebraRepository algebraRepository;
  private TrigonometryRepository trigonometryRepository;
  private ChemistryRepository chemistryRepository;
  private AnatomyRepository anatomyRepository;
  private HistoryRepository historyRepository;
  
  public CourseGroupService(
    MathRepository mathRepository,
    BiologyRepository biologyRepository,
    PhysicalRepository physicalRepository,
    EnglishRepository englishRepository,
    AlgebraRepository algebraRepository,
    TrigonometryRepository trigonometryRepository,
    ChemistryRepository chemistryRepository,
    AnatomyRepository anatomyRepository,
    HistoryRepository historyRepository,
  ) {
    this.mathRepository = mathRepository;
    this.biologyRepository = biologyRepository;
    this.physicalRepository = physicalRepository;
    this.englishRepository = englishRepository;
    this.algebraRepository = algebraRepository;
    this.trigonometryRepository = trigonometryRepository;
    this.chemistryRepository = chemistryRepository;
    this.anatomyRepository = anatomyRepository;
    this.historyRepository = historyRepository;
  }

}
```

How to include this class in the service class and how to initialize it in the constructor to no longer have this sonar Qube error

Comment: The formatting rules are there for a reason, having a bean with 11 dependencies means that the scope of that bean is too wide and it is usually a code smell. I would suggest you refactor it into smaller ones with a narrow scope. Having said that, if you feel no refactoring is necessary you can suppress the error. Refactoring the code just for the sake of removing the linter errors does not sound like a great idea.